# Is it possible to get the FileAge to the millisecond?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to get the time stamp of a file when it was last modified to the millisecond. Currently if I use:

```
FileAge(Filename);
```

I will get the last modified date/time to a second. For example: 12:00:54. Is it possible to get the last modified date and time with milliseconds?

Comment: Using FileAge? No. But what makes you think that the OS filesystem keeps it to millisecond accuracy?

Comment: @KenWhite It does, depending on the filesystem: [NTFS = 100ns, says SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/937380/get-creation-time-of-file-in-milliseconds). You can get that value using the [GetFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Yes, I'm aware. But the poster didn't indicate what OS or FS was in use.

Comment: @Ken Pretty surprising if anyone was using a system that didn't have such accuracy these days don't you think.

Comment: @David: Pretty surprising we still get questions here about Delphi 2/3/5 and Windows 95/XP, too. And what about thumb drives that are using FAT32?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`TFile.GetLastWriteTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.GetLastWriteTime)  or [`TFile.GetLastWriteTimeUtc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.GetLastWriteTimeUtc) from the System.IOUtils unit.

If the system supports your desired accuracy then these functions will provide dates to that accuracy. Of course it all depends on the file system in use.

Comment: Note that these are just wrappers for `SysUtils.FileGetDateTimeInfo()`. The returned `SysUils.TDateTimeInfoRec` record has milliseconds precision on Windows, but only seconds precision on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of `FileAge()`:

---

```
function FileAge(const FileName: string): Integer;
```

This version is **deprecated**.

On Windows, it uses [`GetFileAttributesEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa36494.aspx) and/or [`FindFirstFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx) to retrieve the timestamp as a `FILETIME` (which has *100-nanosecond* precision), but then coverts it to a DOS-encoded integer using [`FileTimeToDosDateTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724274.aspx), which has *seconds* precision.

On POSIX, it uses [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html), which returns timestamps as *seconds* elapsed since the epoch.

---

```
function FileAge(const FileName: string; out FileDateTime: TDateTime; FollowLink: Boolean = True): Boolean;
```

On Windows, it retreives the same timestamp as the deprecated version, but coverts the `FILETIME` to a `SYSTEMTIME` and then to a `TDateTime` using *milliseconds* precision.

On POSIX, it uses `stat()`, and thus has *seconds* precision.